# Function returning "None" sometimes, and othertimes returning 1 in nested recursive call

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, return, nonetype

When I run the following code, if I input the correct value of 1 or 2 on the first try, it works fine. However, if I input an incorrect value, the code then correctly prompts me to fix it. And when I then put in a correct value, instead of returning 1 or returning 2, it is returning `None`. Any reason why? Thanks!

```
def check_input(input_message, option1, option2):
    response = input(input_message + ":\n").lower()
    if int(response) == option1:
        return 1
    elif int(response) == option2:
        return 2
    else:
        print_pause("I'm sorry I don't recognize that response. Try again!", 2)
        check_input(input_message, option1, option2)

decision = check_input("Please type 1 to go into the dark cave. 2 to go into the dweilling", 1, 2)
```

Comment: `return check_input(input_message, option1, option2)`

Comment: Check the link to the duplicate. It would be easier for your function to contain a `while` loop to repeat the question rather than have a recursive call.

Comment: Not just easier, but more efficient and more correct (as it eliminates the possibility of a `RecursionError` due to a stubborn user).

Answer (score 0):

Change the last line of the `else` block to be:

```
return check_input(input_message, option1, option2)
```

Otherwise, your function won't return any value (that's why you got `None`)